# John the Ripper on shadow file

Tags: password-cracking, kali-linux, sha, md5

If I have a shadow file I want to crack the hashes of, will john start with the first user and go through all attempts at that, then move on to the next?

If that's the case, if the first user's hash is encrypted with sha512, but the rest are using md5, how can I tell john to not waste time on the sha512 ones and only work on the easier md5 ones? I've been looking up john examples, but can't seem to figure this out. Basically I'm looking for like a "low-hanging fruit" flag to use with john on a shadow file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

--format=md5 option I think is what you are looking for, here are some pretty decent guides on options

http://www.openwall.com/john/doc/OPTIONS.shtml

http://www.liatsisfotis.com/2012/12/crack-passwords-using-john-ripper.html

Comment: I would run 2 attacks, one for the md5 ones and one for the ones you're not sure about. Done in whatever order you want.

Comment: Your second link is broken.